# selenium download file using PhantomJSDriver (java)

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I just wanted to know is it possible or no to download a file using PhantomJSDriver in selenium tests on Java? If yes, provide an example please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you even used the search or google here? At least show somethings what you researched and maybe what you did

Comment: Of course I have. There is a page on github https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052 where the problem is discussed. But still  not clear a solution for java.

Answer (score 0):

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
'application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get('some URI')
link = driver.find_element_by_...('some criterion')
link.click()
```

try this.

Comment: I need PhantomJS driver!! Not firefox